# PHP.ini doesn't load in command line after changing local server

Tags: php, windows, mamp

After changing from XAMPP to MAMP the loaded configuration file isn't loaded in command line.

```
Runnung php --ini..
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

The php.ini works fine when loaded from localhost with `phpinfo();`.

Since there is no php.ini I get the following message when running composer command for example..

```
  [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex
  tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
```

Edit: I know that enabling extension=php_openssl.dll will solve the NoSslException in php.ini but the question is how to load the correct php.ini in command line?

Comment: php-cli uses its own php.ini file. `php --ini` reported the ini file is found inside `C:\WINDOWS` directory, check there

Comment: and sometimes you need to reopen the shell or to reload the profile, in order to get the new config work

Comment: @Ali there is no php.ini file in C:\WINDOWS.

Comment: @fucethebads I have already restarted the computer, what do you mean by reload profile?

Comment: when you open a shell/terminal a context will be opend where some variables are defined. if you change some of them, they wont be refreshed in your context. so to refresh them you have to open a new shell or reload the context. on linux systems the context is knows als profile